# Pivot Data and Count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a dataset in SQL that looks similar to this:

```
date        dayssinceend
02/07/2020  1
03/07/2020  2
04/07/2020  3
05/07/2020  4
06/07/2020  5
01/07/2020  1
02/07/2020  2
03/07/2020  3
04/07/2020  4
01/07/2020  1
02/07/2020  2
03/07/2020  3
04/07/2020  4
```

I want to pivot it so that the date is on the Y axis and the Days since end is on the X Axis

So it would look like this:

```
Date        1   2   3   4   5
01/07/2020  2   0   0   0   0
02/07/2020  1   2   0   0   0
03/07/2020  0   1   2   0   0
04/07/2020  0   0   1   2   0
05/07/2020  0   0   0   1   0
06/07/2020  0   0   0   0   1
```

The Days since end will change so if there's away of doing this without setting the values to be static then that would be great.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL if you don't know the days-since values.

Comment: can you group by date and then cout for each value of dayssincend (but to make something dynamic you must  create some SQL procedure )